# Use of dim() in the lapply command

Tags: r

I have a list which contains again multiple lists of matrices of the dimensions `3834 1`. So all values are basically stored in one column. Now I want to adjust the dimensions of the single matrices of each sublist, so that the new dimensions are `54 71`.

Here is some code to reproduce sample data:

```
######################### create sample data ###########################
# create empty list
list1 <- list()

# fill the list with arrays/matrices
for (i in 1:10) {
  list1[[i]] <- array(sample(1:100, 600, replace=T), dim= c(54*71,1))
}

# create the big list
big_list <- list()
for (i in 1:8) {
  big_list[[paste0("list", i)]] <- list1
}
```

The goal can be achieved by using a `for` loop:

```
# adjust the dimensions of the matrices by using for loop
for (i in 1:length(big_list)) {
  for (j in 1:length(big_list[[1]])) {
    dim(big_list[[i]][[j]]) <- c(54,71) 
  }
}
```

I am sure that there is a more elegant way than using five lines for this, most likely by using `lapply/apply/tapply` etc. But I could not figure out how to place the `dim()` and `c(54,71)` properly in the command.

Anybody with a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, the code

```
f(x) <- y
```

is equivalent to

```
x <- `f<-`(x, value = y)
```

With that in mind, you can use (nested) `lapply` with `dim<-`:

```
big_list <- lapply(
    big_list,
    function (lst) lapply(lst, `dim<-`, c(54L, 71L))
)
```

… and *in principle* you can omit the anonymous function — but whether that’s readable is debatable:

```
big_list <- lapply(big_list, lapply, `dim<-`, c(54L, 71L))
```

Comment: Perfect, the second one liner is exactly what I was looking for. In my view it is quite readable. Also thanks for the general input Konrad Rudolph!

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, `map_depth()` from `purrr` is useful to dig into nested lists.

```r
library(purrr)

map_depth(big_list, 2, matrix, nrow = 54, ncol = 71)

# or
map_depth(big_list, 2, `dim<-`, c(54L, 71L))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, that did the job perfectly too. And in addition, it is quite simple.